# Is there a better way to handle warnings for built-in algorithms when using TrainingJobAnalytics function in sagemaker sdk?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When using [TrainingJobAnalytics](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/analytics.py) function in sagemaker sdk to view training job results, I get a bunch of scary looking warnings which I understand are harmless.

The function checks for metric statistics from cloud watch for each metric definition defined in training job configuration. From what I understand the implementation allows to keep the logic generic enough to handle custom(byoc) algorithms as well as inbuilt and avoid hard-coding.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this and avoid the warnings instead of suppressing them.

[warnings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BWoE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this amount of warning message is by design and since `TrainingJobAnalytics` is used, fetching metrics for analytics is expected. But I do think we should provide users a way to opt-in warning messages for this particular function if it's too much. We'll be planning and working on adding an optional arg to avoid the large amount of warning messages.